MySQL endless increasing InnoDB .idb file size when doing INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field = CONCAT(field, 'new data') on a LONGTEXT field
I can't find a solution/explanation for a situation I'm facing without changing the code logic (I don't want to do that). The table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `output` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lastUpdate` (`lastUpdate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

on which I do thousands/hundreds of thousands of
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (someFixedID, someTimestamp, 'some 2KB string')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `lastUpdate` = sameTimestamp, `output` = CONCAT(`output`, 'same 2KB string')

multiple per second. Normally I would expect the table size to increase somewhat gradually with approximately +2KB per query. At first this is what is happening, but after a while (after dozens of thousands of queries) the table/.idb file size starts to increase exponentially, reaching even 50-100GB+ even if the actual table data is probably around only ~50-100MB.
Usually there are at most 5-10 entries in the table.
Why is this happening? Any way to avoid this without changing the code logic? One code logic change would be to insert each new data update as a separate row instead of concatenating the data each time in a single row, but for various reasons I want to have the data in a single row.
As a temporary hack I am doing periodic OPTIMIZE TABLE table which successfully trims the table/.idb file size to the ~actual data size. It's ugly but it works until I decide to actually change the code logic.

Could it be increasing by 16KB per IODKU?

@RickJames that doesn't seem to be the case. The bigger the CONCAT() data is, the larger the growth is.
For what it's worth, if I query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES and check the Data_free field for that table during the INSERT...UPDATE, the value for Data_free changes abruptly and continuously in big ranges: 1MB-400MB-30MB-etc

Note that data_free only measures empty extents, which are contiguous blocks of 64 pages. Data_free is bound to be in multiples of 1MB.
